# What characters are valid in an SQL Server database name?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, identifier

We're going to provide our clients with a tool that (among other things) creates a new SQL Server database, and I want to be able to do basic validation on the database name they provide. SQL Server's documentation explains what characters are valid in a database name. However, the documentation is apparently incorrect, because I can successfully create databases whose names violate the documented rules.

According to SQL Server's documentation for [CREATE DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx), database names must comply with the rules for identifiers; and the rules for [identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx) depend on the database compatibility level. When the compatibility level is 100 (which, according to SQL Server Management Studio, means "SQL Server 2008"), the name must start with a Unicode letter, `_`, `@`, or `#`; followed by one or more letters, numbers, `@`, `$`, `#`, or `_`. The documentation clearly states that embedded spaces or special characters are not allowed.

This flies in the face of the available evidence, because I can use SQL Server Management Studio to create a database whose name is `This & That | "Other"` -- which not only contains embedded spaces (explicitly forbidden), but contains special characters (`|`, `"`) that aren't even valid in a filename. I checked, and the database's compatibility level is indeed "SQL Server 2008 (100)", even though its name is documented to be invalid at that compatibility level.

Heck, I can even do `CREATE DATABASE " "` (yes, that's a single space), which proves that the first character does *not* have to be a letter, underscore, at sign, or pound sign.

So I guess my question is, what characters **are** valid in an SQL Server database name? Are there any documented rules that are consistent with SQL Server's actual behavior?

Comment: What's the value in using invalid or extremely unusual character(s) for a database, table, etc name?  Other than ensuring that those who have to use your database curse your name...

Comment: It'll be up to the users to decide what to call the database. If they want to pick a wretched name, my understanding at this point is that we don't want to stop them. (That may change, but I at least want to know what we have to work with.)

Answer (score 32):

The [rules for identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx) state at the end:

> When identifiers are used in
>   Transact-SQL statements, the
>   identifiers that do not comply with
>   these rules must be delimited by
>   double quotation marks or brackets.

By choosing a database name which does not conform to those rules, you *have to* enclose it always with double quotation marks or brackets.

If the rules for regular identifiers are respected, you may use your database name without quotes/brackets.

The following instructions are ok

```
CREATE DATABASE [conformingName]
CREATE DATABASE conformingName
CREATE DATABASE [This & That | "Other"]
```

but not

```
CREATE DATABASE This & That | "Other"
```

EDIT:

I agree that this is not how one would understand the linked documentation: What does *must comply with the rules for identifiers* mean if the rules do not apply anymore as soon as the identifier is enclosed? The point about enclosing non conforming identifiers should be part of the rules.

Comment: Okay, I see. But the docs don't seem to say anything about what is and isn't valid inside those quotes. Does that mean *anything* goes? Illegal Unicode characters? `\0`? Or are there still rules?

Comment: Try it! Yes, anything goes. I created a database name called ~`^%$£"

Answer (score 12):

There is a difference between regular identifiers and delimited identifiers. A regular identifier is bound by the limitations that you mention, while a delimited identifier can contain any characters (except the delimiter).

As you are using quotation marks around the identifier, it's a delimited identifier, and you are not limited by the rules of regular identifiers.

Without the delimiters you can only create databases with identifiers that follow the rules of regular identifiers:

```
create database db_name
```

With delimiters, you can use pretty much anything:

```
create database "That's a funny name, isn't it?"

create database [)(/%Q)/#&%¤)Q/#)!]
```

Comment: Explain *while a delimited identifier can contain any characters **except** the delimiter* . I can simply type the character twice to escape it, as such: **create database """"** or even **create database []]]**

Comment: @Pacerier: Yes, if delimited identifiers supports escaping, you can even use the delimiter in the identifier.

Answer (score 8):

Personally I would limit them to the alphabet and numbers and nothing else (well possibly also an _). No spaces, no funny symbols, no carriage returns etc. This is the safest you can do.

Comment: doesn't make sense at all. exactly how is it safer ?

Comment: It's true that it's safer in terms of running scripts against the database that may not take special characters into account.

Comment: @Pacerier, you never know what system or code could at some time process your whacky database name and blow up because you used characters it's developer was too short sighted to allow for, even if SQL Server is OK with them.

Comment: Actually, this is not safe at all. When you are programming, you must assume every possibility. If you assume that identifiers are always safe, you open yourself to attacks, such as code injection.

Comment: @galets, this has nothing to do with injection attacks which are prevented more by correcly written code than object names..

Comment: @HLGEM try calling your database "d; drop database master;"

Comment: That's why nothing but letters numbers and underscore. However, you need to smart about it. No one in their right mind would name a database d; drop database master;

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question asks what characters are valid, it doesn't ask for your opinion on what is "safe" to use.

Answer (score 6):

Delimited names - surrounded by square brackets or double quotes (if [QUOTED_IDENTIFIER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx) is set to ON) - can contain basically anything other than the delimiters themselves. It is even possible to use the delimiters within the name with some escape logic. Note though that it is only the closing escape character that must be escaped. In the first example below, the single instance of the opening escape character in the name does not need to be escaped whereas the closing escape character does have to be escaped (by replacing the single instance with two). I guess the logic here is that whatever code that is parsing these statements is looking for a closing escape character and has is not interested in nested opening escape characters.

- [Test[Test] -> Test[Test
- [Test]]Test] -> Test]Test

The following is a description of the rules surrounding non delimited (nonquoted) identifier names in SQL Server 2012. It is an extract from the document [Guide to Migrating from MySQL to SQL Server 2012](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/4/1/041FFD42-EB8B-4CEC-8E51-2CB48F3A8FE9/SQL_Server_2012_Guide_to_Migrating_from_MySQL_to_SQL%20Server%202012.pdf).

> **Schema Object Names**
>
> In SQL Server 2012, an object name can be up to 128 characters long.
>
> Nonquoted identifier names must follow these rules:
>
> - The first character must be alphanumeric, an underscore (_), an at sign (@), or a number sign (#).
> - Subsequent characters can include alphanumeric characters, an underscore, an at (@) sign, a number sign, or a dollar sign.
> - The identifier must not be a Transact-SQL reserved word. Guide to Migrating from MySQL to SQL Server 2012 8
> - Embedded spaces or special characters are not allowed.
>
> Identifiers that start with @ or a number sign have special meanings.
>   Identifiers starting with @ are local variable names. Those that start
>   with a number sign are temporary table names.
>
> To quote an identifier name in Transact-SQL, you must use square
>   brackets ([]).