# Getting a table from a schema from sql with a backslash

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

So I have to get a table which is in a schema in a database. The schema name contains a backslash, e.g david\b.

I have my connection `con` so I use `dbplyr`

```
tabel <- dplyr::tbl(con, in_schema("david\\b", "some_tabel"))
```

But this does not work.

Comment: Have you tried `"david\\\\b"`?

Comment: Databases I'm familiar with wouldn't allow a backslash in a schema name (e.g., [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm), [Postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/45591), [SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4200476/903061)). Are you sure there's a backslash in the schema name? Perhaps it needs to be a quoted name to allow for special characters, maybe `in_schema('"david\\b"', "some_tabel")`

Comment: @Gregor: there is a backslash. I have also tried with two backslashes.

Comment: @r2evans: no it does not work.

Comment: @Gregor: You were right!! Thanks!!

Comment: @Gregor: I used the single quote outside the double quote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every database I know would only possibly allow a backslash in a *quoted identifier*. So I think you need to include the double quotes as well as the (escaped) backslash:

```
in_schema('"david\\b"', "some_tabel")
```

If you click on the links in my comment, they all pretty much say identifiers (like table and schema names) can only  include letters, numbers, `_` and (sometimes) `$` and `@`. *Unless the identifier is quoted*.