# How to access schema with special characters in Databricks SQL connector?

Tags: sql-server, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am trying to access SQL Server from Azure Databricks, but I have an issue with the `schemaname` property.

The schema has a name of the format "XX\YY", so I need to access `[DB_NAME].[XX\YY].[TABLE_NAME]`.

The query I'm using is as follows:

```py
hostname = "XXXX"
username = "XXXX"
password = "XXXX"
schemaname = "XX\\YY"
tablename = "xx"

df_nbpl = (spark.read
       .format("sqlserver")
       .option("host", hostname)
       .option("user", username)
       .option("trustServerCertificate", "True")
       .option("encrypt", "True")
       .option("password", password)
       .option("database", databasename)
       .option("schemaname", schemaname)
       .option("dbtable", tablename) # (if schemaName not provided, default to "dbo")
       .load()
    )
```

So far I think I have tried all considerable combinations for `schemaname`, but none will be recognized.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried something like - `schemaname = '"XX\\YY"'`? Here you'll notice double quotes are quoted further.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the single-double quote doesn't help either. But thx for the suggestion. It was not on my list of things I had tried :)

Comment: I suggested that because as mentioned at the end of the [rules for regular identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN#rules-for-regular-identifiers) - the identifiers that do not comply with these rules must be delimited by double quotation marks or brackets. You may try brackets `[]` as well.

Comment: Also, kindly check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56240562/getting-a-table-from-a-schema-from-sql-with-a-backslash) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200351/what-characters-are-valid-in-an-sql-server-database-name/4200476#4200476) if it helps further.

Comment: The single-double quote helped when combined with adding the schemaname in front of table_name. So correct option was:

```
tablename = '"XX\\YY".xx'
```

Comment: Hey @BjarnePedersen, I have provided a detailed answer to your issue covering the whys and hows of the question asked with the resolution as discussed in the comments. Please kindly take a look at it and if it looks good  - you can accept it as the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Databricks Runtime 11.3 LTS and above, you can use the `sqlserver` keyword to use the included driver for connecting to the SQL server. When working with DataFrames, use the following syntax:

```py
remote_table = (spark.read
  .format("sqlserver")
  .option("host", "hostName")
  .option("port", "port") # optional, can use default port 1433 if omitted
  .option("user", "username")
  .option("password", "password")
  .option("database", "databaseName")
  .option("dbtable", "schemaName.tableName") # (if schemaName not provided, default to "dbo")
  .load()
)
```

As you notice, there is no `schemaname` option separately provided here - contrary to how you are using it in your code. For more details check how to [Query SQL Server with Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/connect/external-systems/sql-server).

As inferred from the code given above you need to provide the value for `dbtable` in `schemaName.tableName` format. So, the first thing you need to do is merge them as follows:

```py
tablename = "XX\\YY.xx"
```

Now, this `tablename` contains two backslashes that don't comply with the [rules for SQL Server database identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN#rules-for-regular-identifiers). And as mentioned below:

> When identifiers are used in Transact-SQL statements, the identifiers that do not comply with these rules must be delimited by double quotation marks or brackets.

So, to solve this for your use case you need to wrap the `schemaName` part of the `dbtable` option inside double quotation marks or brackets as follows:

```py
tablename = '"XX\\YY".xx'
```

or

```py
tablename = '[XX\\YY].xx'
```

This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, the way to query the database was:

```
    hostname = "XXXX"
    username = "XXXX"
    password = "XXXX"
    tablename = '"XX\\YY".xx'

    df = (spark.read
       .format("sqlserver")
       .option("host", hostname)
       .option("user", username)
       .option("trustServerCertificate", "True")
       .option("encrypt", "True")
       .option("password", password)
       .option("database", databasename)
       .option("dbtable", tablename) # (if schemaName not provided, default to "dbo")
       .load()
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**